# Combine polygons for a coveredby query

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis

I am trying to figure out how to run a SQL query for where points fall within certain polygons.

Basically, end-users can enter in N number of polygons, and I need to find all the relevant data within that fall within any of those polygons. I can't figure out a good way to do this apart from using N number of OR clauses...

IE:

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE st_coveredby(geog, <input polygon 1>) OR st_coveredby(geog, <input polygon 2>);
```

etc etc.

I've been trying to create a huge polygon that is basically like the aggregation or union of all of these polygons, but I can't figure out a way to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: Is geog really a point?

Answer (score 0):

You are better off to create an array and use ANY along with an operator.  You currently have:

```
WHERE st_coveredby(geog, <input polygon 1>) OR st_coveredby(geog, <input polygon 2>);
```

Depending on how you have this set up, the @ operator might work:

```
WHERE geog @ ANY(ARRAY[ <input polygon 1>,  <input polygon 2>,  <input polygon 3>])
```

If that doesn't work you could create an operator like:

```
CREATE OPERATOR @@@ (
      procedure st_covered_by,
      leftarg geography,
      rightarg geography
);
```

Then you should be able to do:

```
 WHERE geog @@@ ANY(ARRAY[ <input polygon 1>,  <input polygon 2>,  <input polygon 3>])
```

Comment: I tried creating an operator for that, but unfortunately, the query returned 0 results on something that should have returned hundreds. IE: if I do the OR clause from above, I get the expected rows returned, but with either @ or @@@, I get nothing.